# Can ReactJS return a div in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I just started on ReactJS and came across this error

> Error: Invariant Violation: CarDisplay.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

And the **render** function is this:

```
render: function() {
    var cars = this.state.loadedCars.map(function(loaded) {
        return (
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x300" alt=""></img>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item"><b>Brand: {loaded.brand}</b></li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><b>Model: {loaded.model}</b></li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><b>Fuel: </b></li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><b>Mileage: </b></li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><b>Location: </b></li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><b>Price: </b></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Buy it! <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        );

        console.log(cars);

        return (<div>
                    {cars};
                </div>
            );
    });
}
```

So far I know that error is caused by not returning a **div**, even if blank, but that's not the case. Am I doing something wrong, or React just can't return anything related to Bootstrap? (This is just a small example I was writing as practice, don't mind any minor errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React is ok with bootstrap. You've simply made a mistake by putting return statement of the render method inside of  `.map()` function. Your `render()` method returned nothing, and that's why the mentioned error was triggered. Correct code should look like:

```
render: function() {
    var cars = this.state.loadedCars.map(function(loaded) {
        return (
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x300" alt=""></img>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><b>Brand: {loaded.brand}</b></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><b>Model: {loaded.model}</b></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><b>Fuel: </b></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><b>Mileage: </b></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><b>Location: </b></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><b>Price: </b></li>
                    </ul>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Buy it! <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
       )
  });

  console.log(cars);

  return (
      <div>
          {cars};
      </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: *facepalm* Thank you so much. I also had to change the "class" to "className" and everything is as I wanted.